# Flash AS3 - what should I do for the next step when array already called?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have created a flash and using array inside the flash,

every time an array is called, that array is gone from the list, so what should i do for showing the next frame when all array is gone,

**Example :**

I create an array from 2-11 (it's mean about frame) and this is happened when flash is played

1. 2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11 (array/frame 8 is called so its show and gone)
2. 2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11 (Array/frame 6 is called so its show and gone)
3. 2,3,4,5,7,10,11 (array/frame 9 is called so its show and gone)
4. 2,3,4,5,7,10 (...)
5. 3,4,5,7,10 (...)
6. 4,5,7,10 (...)
7. 4,5,7 (...)
8. 4,5 (...)
9. 4 (...)
10. last array is 4, and its showing last time

now i want when all array is gone ill show the `result Frame` in frame 12,
what should i do for doing that?

Comment: someone have an idea? please help me.

Comment: Make a check if (yourArray.length < 1) { // do what you need }

Answer (score 0):

Until the array is empty, keep showing frames.  Once empty, show the result frame.

```
if (myArray.length > 0)
{
    // Show and remove a frame.
} else {
    // Show result frame.
}
```